# Unable to compile and run xerces based Java program

Tags: java, netbeans, xml-parsing, xerces

I have a Java program, where I am using Apache `xerces.jar` for parsing XML files. I am running into an error, where the error here is:

```
javac -classpath ":." MyParser.java
MyParser.java:4: error: package org.apache.xerces.parsers does not exist
import org.apache.xerces.parsers.*;
^
```

I have tried various options like the below:

```
javac -classpath ":." MyParser.java
javac -cp ":." MyParser.java
javac -classpath ":xerces.jar" MyParser.java
javac -cp ":xerces.jar" MyParser.java
javac -classpath :. MyParser.java
javac -cp :. MyParser.java
javac -classpath :xerces.jar MyParser.java
javac -cp :xerces.jar MyParser.java
```

The main code I have that is causing the issue is:

```
import org.apache.xerces.parsers.*;
```

I am able to perfectly compile this and run this in Netbeans IDE, but I am not able to achieve it using Command Line. The main reason I am going for a command line is, using Netbeans, I am not able to parse a 250 MB file. Does anyone have any idea about how to increase the stack / heap limit?

When I reduce the XML file to less than 10 KB I am able to parse it, but in the current scenario, I am getting this error in the Stack Trace.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/user/Downloads/Project/Test/Parser/posts2.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.reportError(XMLParser.java:1318)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner.reportFatalXMLError(XMLDocumentScanner.java:616)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner$XMLDeclDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentScanner.java:798)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner.parseSome(XMLDocumentScanner.java:381)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:1208)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:1247)
    at MyParser.main(MyParser.java:21)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I believe this is because, the whole file is not getting read or it is reading a truncated file. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is with UTF-8 BOM. Use a decent Hex Editor and remove the first three characters of UTF-8 BOM.

```
EF BB B0
```